# Visual Studio toolbox items disabled after updating to 17.7.2

Tags: visual-studio, controls, toolbox

After updating to version 17.7.2 of Visual Studio 2022, I can no longer use controls in the toolbox.  I see the following:

[image]

If I try to drag an item that appears to be enabled it does not work and the item immediately shows as disabled.

I am working with a Winforms project that was working until I updated it.  I've tried several suggested solutions including repairing Visual Studio, resetting the toolbox, etc.

I can't seem to get the toolbox to the state it was before I updated it.  And, yes, I do have 'useWindowsForms' set to true.

UPDATE:  I may have found the problem.  I am using a NuGet package called AeroWizard that seems to be related because the toolbox items are disabled only on this form.

UPDATE2:  I reverted the 17.7.2 release to 17.6.3 and the controls are now longer disabled for the form.  It appears that the problem is related to the NuGet package.

Comment: Issue happens in me when I migrated to 17.7.4 from 17.6.X. I don't use Nuget package. -- issue fixed after restarting VS